# VHDL multiplication for std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, multiplication

When simulating, I get a run time error, so I'm trying to run a RTL analysis in Vivado to see if the schematic of the component can be created at least. My code is the following:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity multiplicator_test is
    generic(
            WORD_SIZE: natural := 8;
            EXP_SIZE: natural := 3
        );
        port(
            input_1: in std_logic_vector(WORD_SIZE-1 downto 0);
            input_2: in std_logic_vector(WORD_SIZE-1 downto 0);
            result: out std_logic_vector(WORD_SIZE-1 downto 0)
        );
end entity multiplicator_test;

architecture multiplicator_test_arch of multiplicator_test is
    constant SIGNIFICAND_SIZE: natural := WORD_SIZE - EXP_SIZE - 1;

    signal significand: std_logic_vector(SIGNIFICAND_SIZE-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal exponent: std_logic_vector(EXP_SIZE-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal sign: std_logic := '0';
    signal aux: std_logic_vector((2*SIGNIFICAND_SIZE)-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
        aux <= std_logic_vector(signed(input_1(SIGNIFICAND_SIZE-1 downto 0))*signed(input_2(SIGNIFICAND_SIZE - 1 downto 0)));
        significand <= aux(SIGNIFICAND_SIZE - 1 downto 0);
        exponent <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(input_1(WORD_SIZE-2 downto WORD_SIZE-EXP_SIZE-2))+unsigned(input_2(WORD_SIZE-2 downto WORD_SIZE-EXP_SIZE-2)));
        sign <= input_1(WORD_SIZE-1) or input_2(WORD_SIZE-1);
        result <= sign & exponent & significand;
end architecture multiplicator_test_arch;
```

When running the analysis, I get:

> ERROR: [Synth 8-690] width mismatch in assignment; target has 3 bits, source has 4 bits [(...)/multiplicador.vhd:27]

The line with the error is 27:

```
aux <= std_logic_vector(signed(input_1(SIGNIFICAND_SIZE-1 downto 0))*signed(input_2(SIGNIFICAND_SIZE - 1 downto 0)));
```

Apparently the target (aux) is 3 bits, but really it should be 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line you've posted is not line 27, line 27 is the following:

```
exponent <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(input_1(WORD_SIZE-2 downto WORD_SIZE-EXP_SIZE-2))+unsigned(input_2(WORD_SIZE-2 downto WORD_SIZE-EXP_SIZE-2)));
```

As you can see, exponent only has 3 bits:

[image: Exponent]

The unsigned addition will need an additional bit for carry-out.
Basically, there's an issue that you might overflow on the multiplication.

One way to solve this is to make your result and exponent one bit wider:

```
result: out std_logic_vector(WORD_SIZE downto 0)
signal exponent: std_logic_vector(EXP_SIZE downto 0) := (others => '0');
```

Yields:
[image: Schematic]

Comment: I really can't believe I was making such a stupid mistake, thanks a lot!

Comment: I've made wayyy dumber mistakes :). Glad I could help.